# Как заставить nuxt@auth и nuxt-i18n подружиться

Tags: javascript, vue.js, auth, i18n, nuxt.js

В приложении используется модуль nuxt@auth с требованием авторизации ко всем страницам. Решили добавить nuxt-i18n. Настройка прошла успешно кроме одного пункта, при переименовании маршрутов:

```
pages: {
 login: {
  en: '/authorization',
  fr: '/autorisation'
 }
}
```

Не удается указать модулью nuxt@auth страницу для авторизации. По умолчанию делает редирект на /login. Перезаписать можно указав только один адрес. Как настроить так чтобы при редиректе на страницу авторизации, модуль проверял выбранный язык, получал бы его ссылку и сделал правильный редирект? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: как вариант отключить редирект поставив false и редиректить самому

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько , спасибо, сделал с помощью middleware для router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему так, сделал плагин для nuxt-auth

```
export default function ({ app }) {
   const loginPage = app.localePath({ name: 'login' })
   app.$auth.options.redirect.login = app.$auth.options.redirect.callback = loginPage
   app.$auth.options.redirect.home = app.localePath({ name: 'index' })
}
```